# MongoDB - Aggregation Method

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

How to use aggregation method using MongoDB compass? May be an example with the output would be really helpful.

From a large amount of data had to find out how many people are interested in Golf. We used $match and $group focusing on a unique data type. But we aren't getting proper output.

[image: 1]

Comment: good practice is to add example document as text/json ( not picture ) and add example of how your output is expected to look like ..   ( not to mention that almost nothing is seen in the attached picture )

Comment: @R2D2 Please specify exactly what do you need from my end? Shall I send the actual task file and datasets please ?

Comment: good practice is to add example document as text/json ( not picture ) and add example of how your output is expected to look like .. ( not to mention that almost nothing is seen in the attached picture )

Comment: use `$match` if you want tofetch whole document

The `$group` stage separates documents into groups according to a "group key"